# Optional chaining and await

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, optional-chaining

Is there any reason to use `if` to check if method exists, before calling await

```
if (someObject.save){
  await someObject.save();
}
```

rather than using nullish coallescence diectly with `await`

```
 await someObject.save?.();
```

Is second code a safe alternative to the former?

Comment: There is no difference (except if `save` were an empty string, `false`, `NaN` or the number zero, but in that case you'd probably have another issue entirely).

Comment: With the optional chaining operator, if it was nullish you'd be effectively doing `await undefined` which does nothing, so it's all good.

Comment: Should be fine, but one thing to note:   if save is meant to return something, then this wouldn't be ideal.  Also readability is slightly reduced, the if statement make logic flow more obvious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is second code a safe alternative to the former?

Yes. But maybe not for the reason one might expect.

The two pieces of code are equivalent in terms of the check made:

```js
const obj = {
  foo() { console.log("method called"); },
  bar: 42
};

if (obj.foo) {
  console.log("obj has foo");
  obj.foo(); //works
}

console.log("using optional chaining");
obj.foo?.(); //works


if (obj.bar) {
  console.log("obj has bar");
  try {
    obj.bar(); //error
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("bar cannot be called");
  }
}

console.log("using optional chaining");
try {
  obj.bar?.() //error
} catch (err) {
  console.log("bar cannot be called");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

However, in terms of async semantics, there is a difference: `await` will force an async function to pause. While not having `await` will run the function until another `await` is encountered or the function finishes and a result is produced.This *can* lead to very subtle bugs. Consider this case when the behaviour overlaps - there is a `save()` method, so both functions pause to `await` its result:

```js
let x = 1;
async function testIf(someObject) {
  console.log("testIf 1:", x); //some external variable
  if (someObject.save){
    await someObject.save();
  }
  console.log("testIf 2:", x); //some external variable
}

async function testOptional(someObject) {
  console.log("testOptional 1:", x); //some external variable
  await someObject.save?.();
  console.log("testOptional 2:", x); //some external variable
}

const obj = { 
  save() { return Promise.resolve(); }
}
testIf(obj);
testOptional(obj);

x = 2; //change external variable
```

The behaviour is consistent: both of these will stop at the line with `await`, which will yield the execution, which then processes the new assignment to `x`, so then when both functions resume, they both read the new value of `x`. This is *expected*.

Now, consider what happens if the `await` line is *not* hit in the `if` version:

```js
let x = 1;
async function testIf(someObject) {
  console.log("testIf 1:", x); //some external variable
  if (someObject.save){
    await someObject.save();
  }
  console.log("testIf 2:", x); //some external variable
}

async function testOptional(someObject) {
  console.log("testOptional 1:", x); //some external variable
  await someObject.save?.();
  console.log("testOptional 2:", x); //some external variable
}

const obj = {}
testIf(obj);
testOptional(obj);

x = 2;
```

The semantics changed. For the `if` version the `await` line is not processed, thus the execution does not yield until the function finishes, thus it reads the value of `x` *before* the reassignment both times. The version that uses optional chaining preserves its semantics even if `save` is not present - it still encounters the `await` and still yields.

In summary, having *optionally asynchronous operation is the path to madness*. I would suggest avoiding it at all costs.

Read more about this:

- [Callbacks, synchronous and asynchronous](https://blog.ometer.com/2011/07/24/callbacks-synchronous-and-asynchronous/) by Havoc
- [Designing APIs for Asynchrony](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/) by Isaac Z. Schlueter
- [Intentionally unleashing Zalgo with synchronous promises](https://bluepnume.medium.com/intentionally-unleashing-zalgo-with-promises-ab3f63ead2fd) by Daniel Brain

And yes, the code I showed is also probably bad - you most likely should not rely on external values. Yet, sometimes you have to. And even if *you* do not rely on them, in the future, somebody consuming your code might. It is best to just avoid Zalgo in the first place and have more predictable code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine as you would `await undefined`.

Some considerations from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls):

> const result = someInterface.customMethod?.();

> if there is a property with such a name which is not a function, using ?. will still raise a TypeError exception "someInterface.customMethod is not a function".

> Note: If someInterface itself is null or undefined, a TypeError exception will still be raised ("someInterface is null"). If you expect that someInterface itself may be null or undefined, you have to use ?. at this position as well: someInterface?.customMethod?.().

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this (I think) would be if you are working in a group where the group has decided not to use `?.` because not everyone understands it. Otherwise, no. The second isn't safer