# Is using a promise within an if-statement condition clean code?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following block of code:

```js
if (raceIsFinished) {
  // give reward if won, give retry if lost
} else if (await CalculateStep()) {
  // race is not finished, see which Step to take next
} else {
  // step or race not found, throw error ..
}
```

Having the promise to be in a condition block makes me think that it isn't clean, but I do not want to start calculating if the race is already finished and so I place it in the else condition block.
Is there a cleaner way on how to do this?

Comment: I don't think a `Promise<boolean>` makes a whole lot of sense, personally.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley — Why ever not?

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Not sure why it doesn't make sense. I make a call to check if I'm logged in, `Promise<boolean>` sounds correct.

Comment: It does not look like an anti-pattern, what's bothering you?

Comment: the result/resolve of `raceIsFinished` could trigger the next step, right? In other words, there is no reason to code out a dedicated `if` bcs it's already baked in to the anync function?

Comment: That's what `await` is for. To make it look synchronous no matter where you use it.

Comment: @RuanMendes I usually check the values of a promise within a variable before using it as a condition and in this case I do not want to run the promise if I don't need to.. Just doubting if placing it within a condition is clean?

Comment: "// do something else in the meanwhile": won't do that [as the condition might not be met](https://jsfiddle.net/j5nbtsko/).

Comment: Let me make it more sense. Editing the Block!

Comment: Is your call to check login status async?  Probably not.  It's probably in your app state somewhere and fetched synchronously, so it's never a `Promise` @RuanMendes

Comment: This *could* be a problem by introducing slight semantic differences in how the function is evaluated. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350613) which deals with conditional asynchronous logic. It's not *guaranteed* to cause a problem but there is a chance when `raceIsFinished = true`, then the `await` won't be reached, thus the if chain will have different ways to be evaluated in terms of other running code. Note that if you had an `await` earlier, this is likely a non-issue.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Yes it's async  `GET /api/session`

Comment: @VLAZ Couldn't that be avoided by making it an async function ensuring a Promise is always returned?

Comment: @RuanMendes fair, but not a penalty I'd want to pay on every request.  Most of the apps I build now are oauth protected, so the token metadata will be floating around _somewhere_ to be fetched without a network call.

Comment: Alright, so I'm going to assume that this is very much Opinion based. As long as it makes sense and is readable, then it can be considered as clean.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Much appreciate the quick replies!

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Not every app uses only oauth. It was just an example.

Comment: @RuanMendes you can see the example in my answer. An async function *is* used but because of the conditional `await` it either runs in the current event loop tick or a next one which changes when it will read external values.

Comment: Would I code it like that? No.