# Make a function dynamically async depending on a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to make a function that would help me try/catching code when I don't care if the code fails:

```js
function failSafe(callback) {
  try {
    return callback()
  } catch(err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Actually, I have a `failSafeAsync` version where the callback is `awaited` before being returned in order to be effectively caught.

I am trying to find a solution to use **the same function for **sync** and **async** code**. I think this may be possible with appropriate manipulation of promises but I don't see how.

Could you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: "*I am trying to find a solution to use the same function for sync and async code.*" don't. Unless you really want to test the limits of your sanity. See the links [at the end of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350613/)

Comment: How do you want to recover if the code fails? If you want to restart your entire program, the events [`uncaughtException`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception) and [`unhandledRejection`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) might help you.

Comment: This is a very good question since it in fact says why we should avoid async functions. It's just the way it is. You can make a standard function returning a promise or not. Then check `returnValue instanceof Promise` and decide accordingly what to do next.

Comment: @Redu Thanks, would you add that as an answer with a bit of code ? If not, I'll try answering based on your comment because it's a relevant sugestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may come up with an implementaion as follows. The `failsafe` function either returns the expected result or catches error and returns `undefined`. Obviously if the callback is an async function then you will get a promise resolving either to the expected value or undefined in case an error is caught in promise.

```js
async function fa(p){
  return await new Promise((v,x) => Math.random() < 0.5 ? x("async oops") : setTimeout(v,100,p));
}

function fs(p){
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {throw new Error("sync oops")};
  return p;
}

function failsafe(cb,...args){
  var result;
  try{
    result = cb(...args);
    return result instanceof Promise ? result.catch(e => console.log(e))
                                     : result;
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log("error caught: ",err);
  }
}

(async function topLevelAwait(){
   var result = Math.random() < 0.5 ? failsafe(fa,10) : failsafe(fs,11);
   result instanceof Promise && (console.log("promise"),result = await result);
   console.log(result);
})();
```

Best to run in dev tools..